# Separating the Variables Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem:** Solve the initial value problem 
$$y′ = \frac{1+3x^2}{3y^2 −6y},\quad y(0) = 1$$
and determine the interval in which the solution is valid. Hint: To find the interval of definition, look for points where the integral curve has a vertical tangent.

Hi! I have this problem from one of my homework's and I am stuck on the part of determining the interval. I have already separated the variables and found C using the initial condition and got:

```
y^3 - 3y^2 = x + x^3 -2.
```

Now I need to determine the interval for the solution. I tried to understand the hint but can't really figure what they mean by looking for points where the integral curve has a vertical tangent. Do I accomplish this by setting:

```
dx/dy = 0
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the original DE, $y'$ is undefined (vertical tangent) when $y\in\{0,2\}$ as the denominator vanishes then.
These values can be solved for the corresponding x-values through the equation for the solution

$$y^3-3y^2=x^3+x-2 \tag{1}$$

For $y=0$
$$x^3+x-2=0 \implies (x-1)(x^2+x+2)=0 \implies x=1,x=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt7}{2}$$
with the only real solution $x=1$.

For $y=2$
$$x^3+x+2=0 \implies (x+1)(x^2-x+2)=0 \implies x=-1,x=\frac{1\pm i\sqrt7}{2}$$
with the only real solution $x=-1$.

Since the initial condition is between these two values, one could argue that it, and hence the solution as given in (1), apply only over the open interval $(-1,1)$.

---

*Remark*

If it is known that for $y=f(x)$ the function $f$ is continuous at $-1$ and at $1$, then these can be used as initial values for the solutions on $(-\infty,-1]$ and $[1,\infty)$ but this information is not given.

Comment: Wow... Thank you so much for this detailed answer! You explained it better than my teacher could in two hours... I completely forgot that y' is the derivative and the graph has a vertical tangent when the derivative either goes to infinity or -infinity.

Comment: You're welcome! It's nice to answer a question that shows the work done towards a solution.